# C++ method declaration is incompatible with

Tags: c++, class, struct, private

Here is a simple c++ class for binary tree. Compiler throws an error:

> E0147 declaration is incompatible with "void BinaryTree::getLeftChild(node *n)"

Here `node` is a struct defined under the `private` section in the class. I am not sure why it says incompatible declaration.

```
//------------------------ BinaryTree class-----------------
class BinaryTree
{
public:
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();
    void createRootNode();
    void getChildren();
    void getLeftChild(node* n);
    void getRightChild(node* n);

private:
    typedef struct node
    {
        node *lchild = nullptr;
        int data;
        node *rchild = nullptr;
    }node;

    queue <node*> Q;
    node *root; 
};

BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
    createRootNode();
    getChildren();
}

void BinaryTree::createRootNode()
{
    root = new node();
    cout << "Enter value for root node" << endl;
    cin >> root->data;
    Q.push(root);
}

void BinaryTree::getChildren()
{
    while (Q.empty == false)
    {
        getLeftChild(Q.front());
        getRightChild(Q.front());
        Q.pop();
    }
}

void BinaryTree::getLeftChild(node* n)
{

}

void BinaryTree::getRightChild(node* n)
{

}
```

**Code picture with errors**

[image]

Comment: Just curious, but how an outer function will use your `getLeftChild(node* n)` if `node` is private?

Comment: Before this `BinaryTree` class, do you have a `class node` or `struct node` somewhere?

Comment: @Peter The function definition of `void BinaryTree::getLeftChild(node* n)` is exactly equivalent to if the OP had written `void BinaryTree::getLeftChild(BinaryTree::node* n)`; the compiler knows we are "inside" `BinaryTree` because of the `BinaryTree::`. The problem is that the function declaration references a `node*`, but `node` was not declared before then (I assume it was declared, as a different, unrelated type).

Comment: Looks to me like you should be able to move all of the `public` stuff below the `private` stuff and be done in time to join the gang fro some pizza.

Comment: Binary trees have only two  child notes, the right and the left, so I don't quite grasp what the `queue` is bringing to the table.

Comment: @Justin : you are correct. I got another struct named as node declared in global scope. After fixing this and changing the order of private and public sections, every thing went good.

Comment: This is destined for rethought regardless. the `getXYZChild` functions are taking a node pointer by value and return `void`. therefore, there is no vehicle for them to "get" *anything*. The`getChildren` API is no better. It gets nothing, and in reality is just clearing the queue `Q`.

Comment: @user4581301 : This code purpose is to request input from user to enter value for root node followed by child node values. User enters -1 when there is no left or right child for a node. we need to keep track of which nodes are already handled. For this purpose, am using a Queue.

Comment: @ringul that makes sense temporarily while building the tree, but doesn't make a useful permanent member. Once you have built the tree you can probably discard it, so an Automatic variable local to the three building function may make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I got another struct in global scope declared as "node" which created chaos. Secondly, i also need to fix the order of public and private sections.

Here is working code

```
    //------------------------ BinaryTree class-----------------
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    typedef struct node
    {
        node *lchild = nullptr;
        int data;
        node *rchild = nullptr;
    }node;

    queue <node*> Q;
    node *root;

public:
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();
    void createRootNode();
    void getChildren();
    void getLeftChild(node* n);
    void getRightChild(node* n);
};

BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
    createRootNode();
    getChildren();
}

void BinaryTree::createRootNode()
{
    root = new node();
    cout << "Enter value for root node" << endl;
    cin >> root->data;
    Q.push(root);
}

void BinaryTree::getChildren()
{
    while (Q.empty() == false)
    {
        getLeftChild(Q.front());
        getRightChild(Q.front());
        Q.pop();
    }
}

void BinaryTree::getLeftChild(node* n)
{

}

void BinaryTree::getRightChild(node* n)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First error, is that you need to forward declare the node. 
Second error, is that you are trying to access node which is privately declared inside of BinaryTree.

First answer:

```
typedef struct node
{
  node* lchild = nullptr;
  int data;
  node* rchild = nullptr;
}node;

class BinaryTree
{
public:
  BinaryTree();
  ~BinaryTree();
  void createRootNode();
  void getChildren();
  void getLeftChild(node* n);
  void getRightChild(node* n);

private:
  node* root;
};

void BinaryTree::getLeftChild(node* n)
{

}
void BinaryTree::getRightChild(node* n)
{

}
```

Now code compiles fine.

Or if you want to have the typedef defined as private inside, you need the implementation to be inside the class as well.

Second Answer:

```
typedef struct node;

class BinaryTree
{
public:
  BinaryTree();
  ~BinaryTree();
  void createRootNode();
  void getChildren();
  void getLeftChild(node* n)
  {

  }
  void getRightChild(node* n)
  {

  }

private:
  typedef struct node
  {
    node* lchild = nullptr;
    int data;
    node* rchild = nullptr;
  }node;

  node* root;
};
```

Comment: It makes sense to leave the `struct node` declaration inside of the `BinaryTree` class, just make it `public` instead of `private`, and place it above the method declarations so they know what it is: `class BinaryTree { public: typedef struct node { ... } node; ... void getLeftChild(node* n); void getRightChild(node* n); ...};`

Comment: You know that you edit your answer after it's posted, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it is satisfactory now.

Comment: Second option doesn't work. It forward declares `Node`, not `BinaryTree::Node` . This leaves `Node` undefined, something you probably won't see until implementing the member functions . What you suggest for option 1 will work, but it misses the simplest solution: Reorder the declarations in the class so that `Node` comes before the first use.